# Pay U IOS SDK 3.2 Seamless Integration - Mandatory Parameter FURL missing

Tags: payu

I am new to Payment gateway integration. I am integrating the latest PAY U SDK version 3.2 seamless in my App. I am following the code as per the sample App.
I have the key and salt values.
But the Payment is not happening and it always throws an error as mandatory parameter furl is missing. What am i doing wrong.

I am filling in the surl and furl and then creating the request.
should i add something in the project plist file.
I am using xcode 6.3 , ios 8.3 and running on simulator

/*Generate the random transaction id*/
    NSString *letters = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    NSMutableString *randomString = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity: 15];
    for (int i=0; i<15; i++) {
        [randomString appendFormat: @"%C", [letters characterAtIndex: arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t)[letters length])]];
    }

```
self.paymentParamForPassing = [PayUModelPaymentParams new];

self.paymentParamForPassing.key = @"gtKFFx";//@"gtKFFx";
self.paymentParamForPassing.transactionID = @"Ywism0Q9XC88qvy";
self.paymentParamForPassing.amount = @"1";//[@(self.amountToPay) stringValue];
self.paymentParamForPassing.productInfo = @"Nokia";//[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@-%@_%@",self.selectedDeal.title,self.displayCheckInDate,self.displayCheckOutDate];
self.paymentParamForPassing.firstName = @"Ram";//self.currentUser.name;
self.paymentParamForPassing.email = @"email@testsdk1.com";//self.currentUser.email;
self.paymentParamForPassing.userCredentials = @"ra:ra";
self.paymentParamForPassing.phoneNumber = @"1111111111";
self.paymentParamForPassing.SURL = @"https://payu.herokuapp.com/ios_success";
self.paymentParamForPassing.FURL = @"https://payu.herokuapp.com/ios_failure";
self.paymentParamForPassing.udf1 = @"u1";
self.paymentParamForPassing.udf2 = @"u2";
self.paymentParamForPassing.udf3 = @"u3";
self.paymentParamForPassing.udf4 = @"u4";
self.paymentParamForPassing.udf5 = @"u5";
self.paymentParamForPassing.environment = ENVIRONMENT_MOBILETEST;
self.paymentParamForPassing.offerKey = @"test123@6622";

self.paymentParamForPassing.hashes.paymentHash = @"ade84bf6dd9da35d0aab50a5bf61d6272ab0fc488b361b65c66745054aacf1900e3c60b5022d2114bae7360174ebcb3cd7185a5d472e5c99701e5e7e1eccec34";
self.paymentParamForPassing.hashes.paymentRelatedDetailsHash = @"915299224c80eff0eb2407b945a5087556292f58baca25fd05a0bceb6826aa9eb531810001dd4b4677dd928dd60d39eecf843b2189f213f9bb82c5a9483e3aac";
self.paymentParamForPassing.hashes.VASForMobileSDKHash = @"5c0314c2781876f7e0a53676b0d08e1457dafe904d2d15d948626b57409538d51093eef4f15c792b1b9651be7b5659efdd45926e43a1145d68cea094687011ca";
self.paymentParamForPassing.hashes.deleteUserCardHash = @"03e10e892005755f91061121036fb1b10f46202b4138d182f153c5de5c7fd44930ed94b32fac230e59bac1e4ca123aca3297e4b9d25024bf13237db9721fec1a";
self.paymentParamForPassing.hashes.offerHash = @"1e99fdb59bd91c1a85624104c0fcfae34d7fcb850dd17a0b75e7efe49857d15fdefc47dd0d86ca34cbc3a8b580839aea6341a573e4e60dc1ddcf7ecc32bf9cae";

self.paymentParamForPassing.expiryYear = @"2019";
self.paymentParamForPassing.expiryMonth = @"12";
self.paymentParamForPassing.nameOnCard = @“NOC”;//self.selectedCard.cardHolderName;
self.paymentParamForPassing.cardNumber = @"5123456789012346";//self.selectedCard.cardNumber;
self.paymentParamForPassing.CVV = @"123";//self.selectedCard.cvc;
//self.paymentParamForPassing.saveStoreCard = @"1";
self.paymentParamForPassing.storeCardName = @"My TestCard";

self.createRequest = [PayUCreateRequest new];
[self.createRequest createRequestWithPaymentParam:self.paymentParamForPassing forPaymentType:PAYMENT_PG_CCDC withCompletionBlock:^(NSMutableURLRequest *request, NSString *postParam, NSString *error) {
    if (error == nil) {
        UIStoryboard *stry = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
        PayUMoneyViewController *PVC = (PayUMoneyViewController *)[stry instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PVC"];
        PVC.theRequest = request;
        NSLog(@"TheRequest: %@", request);
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:PVC animated:true];
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"URL request from createRequestWithPostParam: %@",request);
        NSLog(@"PostParam from createRequestWithPostParam:%@",postParam);
        NSLog(@"Error from createRequestWithPostParam:%@",error);
        [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:error delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] show];

    }
}];
```

Please let me know if anybody has integrated the PAYU IOS SDK seamless 3.2

Comment: KIndly let me know if anyone has integrated PAY U IOS SDK 3.2 seamless

Comment: Looks like the failureURL (fURL) is not being set properly. Sharing some code might help the debugging process.

Comment: Hi Please find the code i am using to send the request. FURL is sent..

Comment: Hi All..Anybody please help...if you have worked on PayU IOS SDK seamless version

Comment: Does https://payu.herokuapp.com/ios_failure actually exist? It needs to be a  URL which can accept POST requests. This is where PayU will post the data after the transaction fails.

Comment: Hi My Webview was not returning true when shouldStartLoadWithRequest. Now the issue is resolved. But i am having a new issue. It says the Hash calculated is not correct.